# -[Foo class]: message sent to deallocated instance on [super dealloc]

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management

In my class `Foo`:

```
[...]
- (void)dealloc
{
    NSLog(@"Foo is being dealloced!");
    [_property1 release];
    [_property2 release];
    [super dealloc];
}
[...]
```

I get `-[Foo class]: message sent to deallocated instance` on `[super dealloc]`.

`Foo` inherits from `NSObject`. I'm not using ARC yet. Gotta get this done before we move on to ARC.

Any ideas what could cause that?

Comment: if you delete both property releases it works?

Comment: Can't help you without more information... Can you post the .h and .m?

Comment: I assume you never tried to call `[foo dealloc]` (you never should call `dealloc` explicitly, except calling `[super dealloc]` from within your `dealloc`). That's the only thing that would cause the problem that I can imagine.

Comment: Also, do you see your "Foo is being deallocated" message once? Or twice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just had the same problem, and resolved it when i deactivated Zombie Objects. But i absolutely have no technical explanation of why it helped.

Comment: Same here - deactivating Zombie Objects removes this message.

Answer (score 1):

It is the debugger that calls the `class` method after the object is correctly deallocated, presumably to display details in the debuggers variable section.  The following code in Xcode 4.4.1, with zombies enabled, and a breakpoint set is enough the trigger the message.

```
NSObject *object = [[NSObject alloc] init];
[object release];
```

This is not a problem in Xcode 4.6.

See longer answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/14734241/1347502

Answer (score 0):

Can you post more of your code? I tried the following:

```
//  Foo.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Foo : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *property1;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *property2;

@end
```

And

```
//  Foo.m

#import "Foo.h"

@implementation Foo

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self)
    {
        _property1 = nil;
        _property2 = nil;
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    NSLog(@"%s Foo is being dealloced!", __FUNCTION__);
    [_property1 release];
    [_property2 release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

And when I use it from my view controller, it works like a champ, e.g.:

```
//  ViewController.m

#import "ViewController.h"
#import "Foo.h"

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    Foo *foo = [[Foo alloc] init];

    foo.property1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"My name is %@", @"Rob"];
    foo.property2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"My age is %d", 29];

    [foo release];
}

@end
```

I did this test in Xcode 4.5.1. Maybe you can (a) confirm that this works for you; and (b) verify the difference between the above code and your code to diagnose the source of your problem.

What is clear is that the problem is not caused by your definition of `Foo`, but rather is probably a result of how your other class creates and ultimately releases your `Foo` object. You're either calling `dealloc` somewhere, or far more likely, you're just over releasing (a release without a corresponding `alloc` or `retain`).

By the way, I'd suggest running your code through the static analyzer (select "Analyze" on the "Product" menu, or press <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>). You shouldn't have any warnings generated by the analyzer. The static analyzer is excellent at finding all sorts of basic memory management problems that tend to plague non-ARC code.