# How do I avoid a zombies error with xcode 4.5 w/o ARC?

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

When I run my application, which does not use ARC, in the xcode 4.5.1 (LLDB) debugger with zombies enabled, I get this error twice (2) when calling -[super dealloc] (-[NSObject dealloc]):

*** -[V2APIClient class]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x9d865c0
*** -[V2APIClient class]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x9d865c0

When I run the same application in the xcode 4.4.1 (LLDB) debugger, I get the error message once (1).
When I run a slightly earlier version of the same application in XCode 4.3.2, I don't get the error message at all (0). I will retry this with the same/newest code.

FYI - This appears to be exactly the same problem as this other post, which has not yet been answered:
[-[Foo class]: message sent to deallocated instance on [super dealloc]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12841172/foo-class-message-sent-to-deallocated-instance-on-super-dealloc))

I attempted to avoid reposting the same question twice, but I was advised to proceed:
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152226/avoiding-asking-a-question-thats-already-been-asked

Also, I also just asked the equivalent question in the Apple Developer Forums:
https://devforums.apple.com/thread/171282

Finally, here is the essence of my class:

```
@interface ASIHTTPRequestHandler : NSObject {
  id _error;
}
@property (nonatomic,retain) id error;
@end

@implementation ASIHTTPRequestHandler
@synthesize error = _error;
-(id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        self.error = nil;
    }
    return self;
 }

 -(void)dealloc
 {
     self.error = nil;
     [super dealloc];// this is the line that appears to cause the problems
  }
  @end
```

Please help me resolve this problem.
I don't believe I am violating any memory management rules, but this error seems to imply otherwise. I'm hesitant to check in any new code until I can resolve this problem.

Thanks,
Chuck

p.s. For the record, here is the calling code:

```
PanoTourMgrAppDelegate *ptmAppDlgt = [PanoTourMgrAppDelegate getApplicationDelegate];
Settings *settings = ptmAppDlgt.settings;
Identification *identification = ptmAppDlgt.identification;
V2APIClient *v2ApiClient = [[V2APIClient alloc] initWithSettings:settings identification:identification];
NSDictionary *result = [v2ApiClient get_application_status];
BOOL success = [v2ApiClient callWasSuccessful:result];
if (!success)
{
    id error = v2ApiClient.error;
    NSString *mbTitle = nil;
    NSString *mbMessage=nil;
    if ([error isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
    {
        mbTitle = @"Application version no longer suppported";
        mbMessage = (NSString*)error;
        [MessageBox showWithTitle:mbTitle message:mbMessage];
    }
}
[v2ApiClient release]; // This is the line that indirectly causes the messages above
```

Comment: The problem is unlikely to be a result of the above code, but rather how you `alloc`/`init` the object and how you finally `release` it. Unless you're doing something strange, it's got to be a simple case of over releasing. While H2CO3's suggestion is amusing, I'm sure he's not suggesting blindly inserting `retain` statements, because unless your obscenely lucky, you'll just end up with leaks rather than over-releases. You just need to go through and make sure that everything that increases `retainCount` is offset by the appropriate release of the `retainCount`.

Answer (score 3):

If you are messaging a deallocated instance, it is because you haven't managed memory correctly.   You have release that is not balanced by a retain;   an over-release.

First, do a "build and analyze" on your code.  Fix any problems identified.

Next, run under Instruments with zombie detection enabled and turn on the reference count tracking feature.  Then, when it crashes, inspect all the retain/release events to the object in question.  You'll find an extra release.   The challenge is to stick a retain into the right spot to balance the release.

(And as Rob rightly points out, it may simply be a case of an extra call to release.)

Comment: I have done a build and analyze, and I have fixed all problems identified.

Comment: Then did you do the "Next" part?

Comment: +1 for "build and analyze". On "the challenge is to stick a retain into the right spot to balance the release", I'd agree. But sometimes the converse is true, that you should remove your extraneous `release`. The key is that they need to be balanced. (I know you know that bbum, but I say it for the benefit of @ChuckDoucette.)

Comment: I know how to run instruments with the application and to choose the Zombies tool. I do not know how to turn on the reference count tracking feature.

Comment: There are two reasons that the obvious answers don't seem to apply: 1) I check the retain count just before calling [super dealloc] and it is 1 (not 0). 2) I am not calling the class method on the object. This happens when calling [super dealloc].

Comment: FYI - When I stop recording in Instruments, it claims the object in question was allocated but never released (rather than over-released).

Comment: `retainCount` is useless;  don't call it.   Slightly orthogonal, but the configuration for debugging is the same: http://www.friday.com/bbum/2010/10/17/when-is-a-leak-not-a-leak-using-heapshot-analysis-to-find-undesirable-memory-growth/

Comment: Certainly calling retainCount within my own code is useless (and certainly improper if I was using ARC) - but how else can I prove that I am not violating memory management rules, as most people would rightfully assume?

Comment: Just to be clear - I am typing (in the debuggger): (lldb) print (uint)[self retainCount]

Comment: Yeah -- `retainCount` is useless.  Even there.   Use Instruments and turn on the reference count tracking in the Allocations instrument.   That'll show where the actual retain/releases are happening.  You have an extra release or not enough retains.

Comment: This turns out to be caused by the debugger calling the `class` method on the zombie object, not necessarily by problems in the code.  It is fixed in later versions of Xcode. See my answer for a simple test case.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in the debugger in some versions of Xcode.

I've just had it in Xcode 4.4.1 but it is not in Xcode 4.6.  To exercise the bug I created a new "Single View Application" project, switched on "Enable Zombie Objects" in the scheme dialog, and ran the following code in the View Controller, with a break point set on the final line.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSObject *object = [[NSObject alloc] init];
    [object release];

}
```

This results in the following message in the debugger:

> -[NSObject class]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x6a7e330

You can also see the object in the variables section of the debugger now describes its class as `_NSZombie_`.  If you remove the breakpoint the message is no longer shown.  The call to the `class` method is made by the debugger after the object is correctly deallocated.